# Why we are not invoking Events directly?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I've seen many developers when wanting to invoke an `Event` they assign it to a local variable named `handler` and invoke `handler` instead of invoking `Event` directly.
Why we are not invoking Events directly?

```
private void OnSomethingChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingEvent != null)
    {
        SomethingEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also Eric Lippert's [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've posted isn't thread-safe, basically. If the final subscriber unsubscribes in a different thread *after* the `if` check but *before* the invocation, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

One option is to write an extension method:

```
public static void NullSafeInvoke(this EventHandler handler,
                                  object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

You can then write:

```
private void OnSomethingChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    SomethingEvent.NullSafeInvoke(this, e);
}
```

You'd probably want another overload for `EventHandler<T>`, too.

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility of a race condition if the event is not copied (relevant to multi-threaded applications only).

If one thread unsubscribes from the event just after the `null` check leaving nothing subscribed to it, you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand why. There is a simple and pretty safe method:

```
// when constructing of instance, to create empty subscription
public event EventHandler SomethingEvent = delegate { }; 

private void OnSomethingChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    // and call it directly
    SomethingEvent(this, e);
}
```